# Custom route api2.xml of existing module

Tags: magento-1.9

Please help me to override 'app/code/core/Mage/Customer/etc/api2.xml' as need to add custom route in that file.

Thanks

Comment: Why not add them in a custom module in its config.xml?

Comment: Hi Julien
I have extend the file in custom module and added custom route. It is working now.